# how to avoid mysql injection when referencing the web url

Tags: php, web, sql-injection

I have a web page that filtered based on the url path.  The address is something like this:

www.xxx.com/player-profile/?ID=130

The page is filtered using the ID field as follows:

```
$playerid = $_GET['ID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPlayers Where lng_RecordID_PK LIKE ".$playerid."");
```

I want to ensure there are not any security issues with this code.  I figure someone may try and manipulate the url.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure about this , but what about just casting it as int ? would that be safe to prevent injections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ID is numeric there's a very easy and very powerful way of making sure the query remains secure!

```
$playerid = $_GET['ID'];
if (!is_numeric($playerid)) { die(); }
$playerid = mysql_real_escape_string($playerid); // Just in case
```

This code basically makes sure that the ID entered in the URL is numeric, or else it will stop executing the script. If it is numeric, then it will carry on retrieving the data and there is no way of doing any SQL injections.

Hope that helped! :)

Also, you might want to change your query to this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPlayers WHERE lng_RecordID_PK = '".$playerid."' ");
```

Comment: (+1) for thinking outside the box.  I'd do a traditional real escape too, though.  It doesn't hurt to be extra safe.  Who knows what character-encoding hacks it'll prevent.

Comment: Thanks :) and actually, I usually do that too. Added it to my answer

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand it is worth to mention that with the original code a "traditional real escape" will do no good. While in this answer it is properly used, combined with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use either `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string` functions on `$playerid`. Also, enclose the `$playerid` in quotes when inserting it into your query. Finally, avoid using `LIKE` when a simple `=` would do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) as a safe way of executing your SQL queries.